# Server Error is thrown when calling user defined HTTP binding to SAP PI

Tags: c#, ssis, sap-pi, sap-xi

I have a code that calls SAP PI Webservice with the following config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="VMSUpdateVehicleMasterProcessing_Out_SyncBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="VMSUpdateVehicleMasterProcessing_Out_SyncBinding1">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://gtsapgwqas.tmp.local:50000/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&amp;senderService=VMSPlantMaintenance_Q&amp;receiverParty=&amp;receiverService=&amp;interface=VMSUpdateVehicleMasterProcessing_Out_Sync&amp;interfaceNamespace=urn%3ATMP.com%3AERP%3APlantMaintenance%3ACreateUpdateVehicleMaster"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VMSUpdateVehicleMasterProcessing_Out_SyncBinding"
        contract="VMService.VMSUpdateVehicleMasterProcessing_Out_Sync"
        name="HTTP_Port" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

To create an instance to use the method in this webservice, I just use:

```
VMService.VMSUpdateVehicleMasterProcessing_Out_SyncClient c = new VMSUpdateVehicleMasterProcessing_Out_SyncClient();
```

Then, when calling the method, I just use:

```
VehicleMasterResponse response = c.VMSUpdateVehicleMasterProcessing_Out_Sync(vm);
```

This works perfectly as I am able to pass updates and receive the appropriate response. My Problem is, I have to implement this in SSIS. SSIS does not recognize app.config so I tried to create my Basic HTTP Binding. Unfortunately, this message is always thrown when I call the well method:

> Server Error

Here is how I set up my binding and instance:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

            var addess = new EndpointAddress("http://gtsapgwqas.tmp.local:50000/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&amp;senderService=VMSPlantMaintenance_Q&amp;receiverParty=&amp;receiverService=&amp;interface=VMSUpdateVehicleMasterProcessing_Out_Sync&amp;interfaceNamespace=urn%3ATMP.com%3AERP%3APlantMaintenance%3ACreateUpdateVehicleMaster");
            VMService.VMSUpdateVehicleMasterProcessing_Out_SyncClient c = new VMSUpdateVehicleMasterProcessing_Out_SyncClient(binding, addess);
            
            c.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "NAME";
            c.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "PWORD";
```

Basically I just supplied the properties that is in the config file... What causes the Server Error and how to solve this problem?

Comment: First glance: Different than your .config file, you do not have to encode the ampersand in your EndPointAddress - try replacing every `&amp;`with `&`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Now I'm wondering why I haven't thought of this!

Comment: Sometimes you need a second pair of eyes or a [rubber duck](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/).